# How to compare Active Directory to SQL query and find users which match

Tags: powershell

I am trying to pull all users employee number from active directory then pull a list of all users that are inactive in an third party application. Then would like to disable users from AD that are inactive in the third party application that are active in AD.

```
$AD = Get-Aduser -Filter * -Properties EmployeeNumber| Select-Object EmployeeNumber

$SQL = Invoke-sqlcmd -query "SELECT
users.id AS EmployeeNumber
FROM 
table
WHERE
users.id LIKE 'I'" -Database "TestDatabase" -Server "TestServer" | Select-Object EmployeeNumber

$Compare = Compare-Object $SQL $AD -Property 'EmployeeNumber' -Passthru | Where-Object{$_.SideIndicator -Eq '<='} | Select-Object EmployeeNumber

Foreach ($user in $Compare) {
$user = $user.EmployeeNumber
$user
Disable-ADAccount -Identity $user
}
```

I figured the compare would get me only users that are active in Active directory that are inactive in the third party application.
Then these users will be disabled in active directory. I continually am getting all users from my SQL query and not the users who are inactive from my query and active in active directory. So seems that my comparison is incorrect.

Comment: What's the issue that you're facing?

Comment: Oh yeah probably should add what issue I have. I keep getting a list of all inactive users from my SQL query. It is not pulling the inactive users that are ONLY active in Active directory.

Comment: Objects that pnly have `EmployeeNumber` are not useful for the `Disable-ADAccount -Identity` parameter. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/disable-adaccount?view=windowsserver2022-ps#-identity). Why do you lmit the $AD array to only that?

Comment: That is true, I did not think that one through. I would have reached that problem after being able to solve the current problem. For some reason thought I could disable all users from compare using just employeenumber.

Comment: Are you expecting your SQL query to return users who are inactive only if they are active in AD?

Comment: Yeah was hoping to return inactive in the sql query yet active in AD.

Comment: So your SQL query doesn't do any filtering based on the output from AD. You could do something like `$ADList = $AD -join ','` and then add to the bottom of your SQL query `AND users.id IN ($ADList)`

Comment: Will give that a shot, appreciate it.